# Azure role hosting autoscaling block can not boost

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I has written a simple Azure deployment to test Azure Auto-scaling block, which contained two role: one work role , one monitor role hosting auto-scaling block.
I wrote those code followed http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/ step by step,

```
In the onStart() method of monitor role, there is:
{
.....
 scaler = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Autoscaler>();
 scaler.Start();
 return base.OnStart();
}
```

then i deploy them, but only the work role instance can boost successfully, the monitor role instance show it was always busy, 
The azure portal show that error message:

Starting role... Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException [2013-04-27T09:54:57Z])

can someone teach me how to get detailed error stack?
or somebody experienced with Azure can figure out what wrong i happened?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you run it in the Azure emulator?

Comment: emulator told me like that: [link]http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/399750  , sorry i can not post the error message, which was not in  english and was too many.

Comment: maybe, it was a primary c# problem, i am such a newbie to c#..